# Batch save excel file every 10 minutes with date and time name

Tags: excel, batch-file, timer

I using a shared excel file. the file is too big, so when I using it file may be corruption.
I want to make a batch file that can save the file every 10 mins with date-time name, although  while I opened and working on the file.

How I can do it?

Comment: Could you please add some more details by answering following questions: Is the file stored on your computer or e.g. a cloud server? How and which program do you use access and edit the file?

Answer (score 0):

Timers are usually done with ping in batch:

```
ping 0.0.0.0 -w 1000 -n 600
```

will 600 times wait 1 secound: 60->1 minute; 600->10 minutes
and then copy it with

```
copy file.xls "file_%date%_%time~0,2%-%time~3,2%-%time~6,2%"
```